# How can i create a reminder command in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to create a reminder command in discord.py, this command will remind a specific role that an event is coming. For that I saved in a first variable the hours when the event starts and in a second variable I subtracted the hours when the event starts and the minutes in advance.
Then I put the second variable in the async.io function so that the reminder is only given at that time.

For example if the event starts at 20:00 and the advance time is 2 the bot should remind at 19:58

But this does not work and I get the following error on the console:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'datetime.timedelta'
```

Heres the code I have:

```
@bot.command()
async def reminder(ctx, arg):

if arg == 'sap':

    role = 839182749452992639
    message = 'hello '
    event_start_time = timedelta(hours=20, minutes=0)
    advance_time = event_start_time - timedelta(minutes=2)

    await asyncio.sleep(int(advance_time) * 60)

    role = get(ctx.guild.roles, id=int(role))

    for user in ctx.guild.members:
        if role in user.roles:
            userDM = await user.create_dm() if (user.dm_channel is None) else user.dm_channel
            if userDM != None:
                await userDM.send(message + user.name)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot really cast a `datetime.timedelta` object into an integer, if you want to get the total seconds just use the `total_seconds()` method

```py
await asyncio.sleep(advance_time.total_seconds()))
```

Your logic is off though, the function it’s not going to sleep till 19:58, but for 19 hours and 58 minutes, to fix it you have to subtract the current time to the desired time and get the seconds

```py
now = datetime.now() # or utcnow
future = datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day, 19, 58)
delta = (future - now).total_seconds()
 
await asyncio.sleep(delta)
```

Comment: Do i need to put something inside that method? @Łukasz Kwieciński

Comment: If not, it does not work when the clock gets to 19:58 nothing happens. And it was supposed to send a message to remind!

Comment: @BernardoPereira Did your bot go offline/restart? It's possible that the command got canceled. Or you failed to implement this line correctly

Comment: @12944qwerty Nop, It was always online. Maybe I was wrong in the question and it caused confusion. I added a new line in the question, maybe that is what is missing

Comment: @BernarsoPereira, your logic is off, it’s not supposed to sleep till 19:58, but sleep for 19 hours and 58 minutes.

Comment: Ohhhh ok, I see, so how can i make it sleep till that time? Should i make another question or you can answer me here @ŁukaszKwieciński?

Comment: It’s kinda related so I guess I can edit my answer

Comment: Ok, thank you so much it would save me alot of time

Answer (score 2):

Your following lines will produce a timedelta object:

```py
event_start_time = timedelta(hours=20, minutes=0)
advance_time = event_start_time - timedelta(minutes=2)
```

when you are trying to do `int(advance_time)` this produces your error, what you can do is to get the seconds directly from the timedelta object:

```py
event_start_time = timedelta(hours=20, minutes=0)
advance_time = event_start_time - timedelta(minutes=2)
advance_time_seconds = advance_time.seconds
# you already have the difference in seconds, no need to multiply by 60
# can keep the int() so yo get and integer
await asyncio.sleep(int(advance_time))
```

Comment: It does not work, when the clock gets to 19:58 nothing happens. And it was supposed to send a message to remind!

Answer (score -1):

I **already made** a similar command **before**, so try this:

#### Example usage

```py
@client.command(name='timer', help='Create a timer.', usage='<time> [s|m|h] (<message>)')
async def timer(ctx, time, unit, *message):
  if not message:
    message = 'Time\'s up!'
  else:
    message = ' '.join(message)

  time = int(time)
  oldtime = time # time without unit calculation to seconds
  if unit == 's':
    pass
  elif unit == 'm':
    time *= 60
  elif unit == 'h':
    time *= 3600
  else:
    await ctx.send(':x: **ERROR**: Invalid unit.\nUnit can be \'s\' for seconds, \'m\' for minutes or \'h\' for hours.')
    return
  if time > 10000:
    await ctx.send(':x: **ERROR**: Timer can\'t be longer than 10000 seconds.')
    return
  await ctx.send(f':white_check_mark: Creating a timer for **{oldtime}{unit}** with message \"**{message}**\"...\nYou will get mentioned/pinged.')
  await asyncio.sleep(time)
  await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention} **{message}** (**{oldtime}{unit}** passed.)')
```

Comment: Instead of offering your own code, you should suggest ways that could solve their issue itself